# Office 365 developer site SharePoint 2013 preview: can't create a new user profile

Tags: office-365, 2013

I use a Office 365 developer site to get acquainted with SharePoint 2013.

I try to create a new user profile (Admin\SharePoint\User profiles\New profile). I can see all the fields for the new profile
[image]

**But when I press the 'Save and Close' button, the page reloads, but nothing happens (I can see the same filled in fields).**

It could be because some of the fields were not filled in (usually in such a case they are highlighted by red, but I can not see even any changes on the page). I tried to filled in all the fields (not only the field which are marked with *), but the result was the same. I couldn't see any error message and the new user profile was not created. I tried Internet Explorer and Chrome both with no result.

Maybe such a behaviour is by design (I am not sure if I could create a new user profile on Office 365 developer site), but in such a case I think I could see at least the error message.

Also I have an issue with [SP2013 Workflow on this site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49857/office-365-developer-site-sharepoint-2013-preview-spd2013-workflow-is-always-ca). Maybe this issues are related.

**Does anybody have some ideas about the issue?**

Every suggestions are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment but I post it as answer for the sake of formatting.

There is a webpage:

- [Issues you may encounter after you receive the latest SharePoint Online service update in Office 365](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2789555)

with a couple of "user profile" bugs marked as "Resolved".

I believe you can push your ticket onto it through posting in [Office365 forum](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/default.aspx) if you do not have access to opening [Premium Support tickets with Microsoft](http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/24433/84567.aspx#84567)